How can i import successfully bootstrap in html?
That's my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>WebCamera</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="{% url 'livefy' %}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <form action="http://localhost:8000/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Check Face</button>
    </form>
    <h6>Name:{{n}}</h6>
    <h6>Id:{{i}}</h6>
    <div class="container-sm">100% wide until small breakpoint</div>
    <div class="container-md">100% wide until medium breakpoint</div>
    <div class="container-lg">100% wide until large breakpoint</div>
    <div class="container-xl">100% wide until extra large breakpoint</div>
    <div class="container-xxl">100% wide until extra extra large breakpoint</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

and i want to know why my bootstrap is not working?
I Using windows 11,python 3.11,bootstrap 5.3,django 5.0.2
Please Help ME!

Wdym? What did you expect? What did you get? This seems like a flask project. Did you try using the flask_bootstrap extension? Please elaborate so that others can help you.

Also, what happens when you make a request to the referenced link? One possibility is that it is working, but just not in the way that you expected it to.

I think, it should work just fine.
You just need to apply the Bootstrap classes. For example your button should use the
class="btn"

Here from bootstrap docs:
<button type="button" class="btn">Base class</button>

Here's the doc link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/
